# Problem uploading Arduino sketch on ESP8266-12e

Tags: esp8266, mac-os

I have a new Mac OS Sierra installed. I just installed the Arduino IDE and the serial drivers for Mac OS X to make the serial USB port available for esp8266 device

When I try to flash the device through the IDE I have these errors:

```
Arduino:1.8.3 (Mac OS X), Scheda:"NodeMCU 1.0 (ESP-12E Module), 80 MHz, 115200, 4M (3M SPIFFS)"

Archiving built core (caching) in: /var/folders/vz/qxry2ffs3rnd2xtd557pgcf00000gp/T/arduino_cache_169716/core/core_esp8266_esp8266_nodemcuv2_CpuFrequency_80,UploadSpeed_115200,FlashSize_4M3M_244c37a477ed4ef8a63952f7a6e6a50b.a
Lo sketch usa 222149 byte (21%) dello spazio disponibile per i programmi. Il massimo è 1044464 byte.
Le variabili globali usano 31524 byte (38%) di memoria dinamica, lasciando altri 50396 byte liberi per le variabili locali. Il massimo è 81920 byte.
error: failed reading byte
warning: espcomm_send_command: cant receive slip payload data
error: unslip sequence wrong
warning: espcomm_send_command: can't receive command response header
warning: espcomm_sync failed
error: espcomm_open failed
error: espcomm_upload_mem failed
error: espcomm_upload_mem failed
```

What can I do?

Comment: i also try with esptool.py
with this line:
esptool.py --port /dev/tty.SLAB_USBtoUART write_flash 0x00000 /var/folders/vz/qxry2ffs3rnd2xtd557pgcf00000gp/T/arduino_build_657411/Blink.ino.bin 0x40000 /var/folders/vz/qxry2ffs3rnd2xtd557pgcf00000gp/T/arduino_build_657411/Blink.ino.bin

but it keeps "connecting..." forever

then i can't even stop the process

Comment: Just curious but what version of Arduino IDE are you running? I think there may be an issue with newer IDE versions and certain libraries.

Also if you found a solution in another Library it would be nice to post a link to it for others.

Comment: the problem was just the silabs library. i downloaded the latest version and it's working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed another version of the driver from silabs' website and now it's working.

Comment: Accept your own answer to close this question.

Answer (score 1):

**3.x version of ESP8266 libraries**

If you're using the most updated version of the ESP8266 "NodeMCU 1.0 (ESP-12E Module)" board then all you need to do is update your Silabs library.

**2.x version of ESP8266 libraries**

If you're using a 2.x version of the ESP8266 "NodeMCU 1.0 (ESP-12E Module)" board, it is more involved. It comes with a packaged version of pyserial which resolves the wrong versions of the IOKit and CoreFoundation libraries. You will need to edit the pyserial script for your board version manually following the instructions here: https://forum.arduino.cc/t/pyserial-and-esptools-directory-error/671804/5.

An alternative is use the Windows version of the flashing tool provided by Espressif by running it through a Windows emulator or VM. You can find instructions for that here: https://blog.squix.org/2015/05/esp8266-flashing-nodemcu-v10-on-mac-os.html.